# Redisson entries not available after lock released

Tags: caching, redis, micronaut, redisson

I am using Redisson with

```
RLock lock = redissonClient().getLock(key);
try {
  if (lock.tryLock()) {
   // Logic here
redissonClient().getMap().get("key"); // returns value
    lock.unlock();
  }
redissonClient().getMap().get("key"); // returns NULL
} catch (Exception e) {
  LOG.error("Error..", e);
} finally {
  if (lock != null && lock.isLocked() && lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
    lock.unlock();
    LOG.debug("lock released");
  }
}
```

If I don't use locks everything works as expected, but after unlock, the value returned is always null.